# How to check if gcc is installed on my pc

Tags: windows, gcc

How do I check if `gcc` is installed on my pc? I'm running windows 7.

Comment: have you installed it? that should give a clue.

Comment: No i haven't installed it. This is a hand me down, hand me down, hand me down computer so I don't know if it's ever been installed or not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Very simple.

Go to Command Prompt and type

```
gcc -v
```

if gcc is installed on your PC, it should display a host of information, starting with the sentence

> Using built-in specs

and that will indicate that gcc is installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 - right-click on the Start Button and select Command Prompt.
For older Windows systems, click the Start Button and in the search box
type “cmd""

In the
Command Prompt window type “gcc” and hit enter.
• If the output says something like “gcc: fatal error: no input files”, that
is good, and you pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following: gcc --version

Answer (score 0):

you can check by running *gcc* command in the terminal.
If you get something like -
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk0vC.png)

it means it is installed
you can check the current version with
gcc --version
or,
gcc -v